# Capturing STDOUT to then reconcile on the file names

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.6

I've been struggling with this problem for a bit, I am trying to create a program that will create a `datetime` object based on the current date and time, create a second such object from our file data, find the difference between the two, and if it is greater than 10 minutes search for a "handshake file", which is a file we receive back when our file has successfully loaded.  If we don't find that file, I want to kick out an error email.

My problem lies in being able to capture the result of my `ls` command in a meaningful way where I would be able to parse through it and see if the correct file exists.  Here is my code:

```
"""
This module will check the handshake files sent by Pivot based on the following conventions:
- First handshake file (loaded to the CFL, *auditv2*): Check every half-hour
- Second handshake file (proofs are loaded and available, *handshake*): Check every 2 hours
"""
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from csv import DictReader
from subprocess import *
from os import chdir
from glob import glob


def main():
    audit_in = '/prod/bcs/lgnp/clientapp/csvbill/audit_process/lgnp.smr.csv0000.audit.qty'
    with open(audit_in, 'rbU') as audit_qty:    
        my_audit_reader = DictReader(audit_qty, delimiter=';', restkey='ignored')
        my_audit_reader.fieldnames = ("Property Code",
                                      "Pivot ID", 
                                      "Inwork File", 
                                      "Billing Manager E-mail", 
                                      "Total Records", 
                                      "Number of E-Bills", 
                                      "Printed Records", 
                                      "File Date", 
                                      "Hour", 
                                      "Minute", 
                                      "Status")

        # Get current time to reconcile against
        now = datetime.now()

        # Change internal directory to location of handshakes
        chdir('/prod/bcs/lgnp/input')   

        for line in my_audit_reader:
            piv_id = line['Pivot ID']
            status = line['Status']
            file_date = datetime(int(line['File Date'][:4]),
                                 int(line['File Date'][4:6]),
                                 int(line['File Date'][6:8]),
                                 int(line['Hour']),
                                 int(line['Minute']))
            # print(file_date)
            if status == 's':
                diff = now - file_date
                print diff
                print piv_id
                if 10 < (diff.seconds / 60) < 30:
                    proc = Popen('ls -lh *{0}*'.format(status),
                                 shell=True) # figure out how to get output

                    print proc




def send_email(recipient_list):
    msg = MIMEText('Insert message here')
    msg['Subject'] = 'Alert!! Handshake files missing!'
    msg['From'] = r'xxx@xxx.com'
    msg['To'] = recipient_list

    s = smtplib.SMTP(r'xxx.xxx.xxx')
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    s.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Don't parse `ls`.  Ever.  Just use `os.path` and friends.

Comment: Seconding what Kevin said. The correct way to do this is with `os.listdir` and (possibly) `os.isfile`.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, so subprocess seems fairly irrelevant unless you need  to use the `Popen` functionality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse **ls** output is not the best solution here. You can surely do that parsing [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.check_output#subprocess.check_output) result or in any other way, but let me give you an advice.

It is a good criterion of something going wrong if you find yourself parsing someone's output or logs to solve a standard problem, please consider other solutions, like offered below:

If the only thing you want is to see the contents of the directory use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) like:

```
my_home_files = os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~/my_dir')) # surely it's cross-platform
```

now you have a list of files in your **my_home_files** variable.
You can filter them in the way you want or use [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html?highlight=glob.glob#glob.glob) to use metacharacters like that:

```
glob.glob("/home/me/handshake-*.txt") # will output everything matching the expression 
# (say you have ids in your filenames).
```

After that you may want to check some stats of the file (like the date of last access etc.) 
consider using [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat):

```
os.stat(my_home_files[0]) # outputs stats of the first
# posix.stat_result(st_mode=33104, st_ino=140378115, st_dev=3306L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=23449, st_gid=59216, st_size=1442, st_atime=1421834474, st_mtime=1441831745, st_ctime=1441234474)
# see os.stat linked above to understand how to parse it
```